# How can I map ; to : in vimrc so that I don't have to press shift every time to enter commands?

Tags: vim, shortcut, neovim

How can I map `;` to `:` in vimrc so that I don't have to press shift every time to enter commands? Some distros have this in their Vim config by default, but not Parrot OS.

I tried this:

[image]

and even this:

[image]

Neither of those attempts worked.

Comment: See `:help map-comments`.

Comment: Do not add comment `"map ; to enter commands` after mapping commands, it is forbidden, since it will interfere with actual mapping. Move the comment above the mapping command.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put comments after mappings, since comments will be considered as part of `rhs` of the mapping. Try to remove your comments or put it above the mapping like this:

```
"map ; to enter commands
nnoremap ; :
```

This should work. Also see `:help map-comments`:

> It is not possible to put a comment after these commands, because the '"'
> character is considered to be part of the {lhs} or {rhs}.